# DPDK UDP packet payload missing

Tags: dpdk

I am running DPDK 20.08.0-rc4 on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS under VirtualBox 6.1.

I started with l3fwd from DPDK distribution. In prepare_ptype_parser function I replaced original l3fwd_lkp.cb_parse_ptype callback with the following function

```
#include <rte_ether.h>
uint16_t
dump(uint16_t port_id, uint16_t queue, struct rte_mbuf *pkts[], uint16_t nb_pkts, uint16_t max_pkts, void *user_param) {
   for (int i = 0; i < nb_pkts; ++i)
   {     
       struct rte_ether_hdr *eth_hdr;
       uint8_t * addr = rte_pktmbuf_mtod(pkts[i],  struct rte_ether_hdr *)
                                  ->s_addr.addr_bytes; 
       printf("\n\npacket[%d] source %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n", 
              i, addr[0], addr[1], addr[2], addr[3], addr[4], addr[5]);

       rte_pktmbuf_dump(stdout, pkts[i], 1500);
       fflush(stdout);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I run l3fwd as follows

```
sudo ./l3fwd -l 1 -n 1 -- -p 1 --config="(0,0,1)" --no-numa --parse-ptype
```

On a separate VirtualBox Ubuntu instance I generate UDP packet with bash command

```
echo "Hello" > /dev/udp/target_ip/32768
```

The source mac address of the received package is correct, however, rte_pktmbuf_dump does not contain the actual content of UDP packet:

```
packet[0]  source 08:00:27:CB:6A:0C
dump mbuf at 0x100610340, iova=0x12103c0, buf_len=2176
  pkt_len=60, ol_flags=0, nb_segs=1, port=0, ptype=0
  segment at 0x100610340, data=0x100610440, len=60, off=128, refcnt=1
  Dump data at [0x100610440], len=60
00000000: FF FF FF FF FF FF 08 00 27 CB 6A 0C 08 06 00 01 | ........'.j.....
00000010: 08 00 06 04 00 01 08 00 27 CB 6A 0C C0 A8 64 04 | ........'.j...d.
00000020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 A8 64 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 | ........d.......
00000030: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00             | ............
```

I also noticed that for every echo my callback function is invoked three times with the same content dumped.

How do I get the payload of the UDP packed in DPDK?

Comment: can you please cross check with `tcpdump -Q out -nxx -i [interface] ` on the sending interface to DPDK? I agree with you `rte_pktmbuf_dump` shows the packet len is 60. But content is misleading as ethtype is  `08 06` (ARP) and `08 00` (IP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `rte_pktdump_dump`, the packet type is `ARP ethtype 06 08` and `IPv4 ethtype 00 08`. Hence your current assumption of receiving IPv4 is incorrect.

If you need the system to send IPv4 packet, assuming you are using Linux as host, please add static ARP entry so IPv4 packet will send out. you can cross check the same with `tcpdump -Q out -nxx -i [interface]`

Comment: After adding static ARP entry at the sending machine I was able to receive the payload.